# Can there be a difference between entering a URL in the address bar vs window.open(url)?

Tags: browser-cache

Can webpage with window.open(url) end up with a different result because of different caches than entering the exact same url directly in the address bar?

I am convinced there cannot be a difference, but some colleagues think otherwise. Please clarify.

Comment: I don't think so. Double check your developpers tools are activated (or not) and that you specified to bypass cache when they are.

Comment: I don't want to avoid using a cache. I just want window.open to use the same cache as browsing the URL directly from the address bar or by clicking on a URL from outside the browser.

Comment: Sorry, I might have been unclear. I meant I think there is no differences. And if you found some, they might come from your developer tools being open or not.

Answer (score -1):

No, both these mechanisms use same HTTP cache.

Comment: OK - Here we have an intranet website, if the page is loaded from another page using window.open it acts different (doesn't work as it should) than when it's loaded by opening a new tab and manually pasting the URL. Even refreshing the tab that was opened by JS does not change this. I'm flabbergasted...

Comment: Can you describe in details what is the difference?

Comment: Just that it doesn't get processed in the same way. I cleared all caches, different browsers and time after time same result. I now found that if window.location = url is used it works as good as pasting the url in a new tab manually. It's window.open(url, "_blank") which is causing the issue.

Comment: @Pieter *"Just that it doesn't get processed in the same way"* doesn't adequately describe what is different. If sessions are being lost, that has nothing to do with browser cache.

Comment: @KevinB does window.open_blank keep session data while location = URL doesn't?

Comment: @Pieter it *should*, but since we don't know what exactly isn't working we can only speculate on what isn't working.